# How to use VueRouter with Storybook

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, storybook

I'm trying to write a story for a component that references `this.$route.params`. I'm not sure how to synthetically define `this.$route` in the context of a story. I think the solution is to use decorators, but all the examples in the docs focus on rendering, like adding a wrapping `<div>` etc. I'm not sure how to inject values.

I also found [this project](https://github.com/gvaldambrini/storybook-router) which appears designed for this exact situation, but it hasn't been maintained in years and README references outdated syntax that doesn't match modern versions of Storybook, so I don't think it's an option.

Here's what *doesn't* work:

```js
import AssetShow from '../app/javascript/src/site/components/assets/Show'
    
export default {
  title: 'Site/AssetShow',
  component: AssetShow,
  parameters: {
  }
};

export const CustomerSpotlight = () => ({
  components: { AssetShow },
  template: '<AssetShow />',
});
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import StoryRouter from 'storybook-vue-router';

CustomerSpotlight.decorators = [

  (story) => { 

    Vue.use(VueRouter)

    return {
      components: { story },
      template: '<story />'
    }
  }
];
```

The component I'm writing the story for has this:

```
mounted() {
 axios.get(`.../bla/${this.$route.params.id}.json`)
},
```

...which causes Storybook to throw this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')`

Comment: Try memory history mode, it's more suited for this usage. What exactly doesn't work? Are there errors? What are "modern versions" in your case? The question lacks your own code for stories

Comment: @EstusFlask The router is in History mode. I installed storybook last week, so it's whatever the latest version is. I don't think the component code is particularly relevant beyond the fact that it references `this.$route.params`. And $route isn't defined in the story.

Comment: You need MEMORY mode, because you don't want to trigger browser navigation

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your intention is to do something with the story's component based on the route parameters?

If that is the case, then I don't think you need to define the route.params within the story context. I suggest either keeping that code within the component itself, or create an option within the story for the user to simulate adding parameters to the path. Which you can simply have as an input text / select field that you send down to the component as a prop.

Comment: Honestly my main intention is to get the story working without throwing errors. And right now it is erroring because `$route` isn't defined. I'm interested in your idea to define the route with a control, but I don't know how to do that. Can you show me an example?

Comment: If the MEMORY mode fix mentioned by Estus Flask is not desired, you can always add a condition before:
axios.get(`.../bla/${this.$route.params.id}.json`).
Where you check to see if this.$route and this.$route.params exists, and only then execute that code.

Comment: I prefer not to let config logic "leak" into the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I declared something very like yours, with a custom `VueRouter`, but changed the route before returning the `Template`:

```js
const Template = () => {
  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [ { path: '/path/to/component/:param1', name: 'desiredRoute' } ]
  })

  router.replace({ name: 'desiredRoute', query: {...}, params: {...} })

  return {
    components: { MyComponent },
    props: {...},
    template: `...`,
    router,
  }
}
```

Not sure how it's gonna work with the addons you setup, mine was just with interactions addon. There may be some issue in case your component renders before the `router.replace` finishes, because it returns a promise, so you have to handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `vue-router@4` as normal, you can create a decorator for your stories using the decorators key when defining the meta in your stories file.

```
const meta = {
...
  decorators: [
    () => {
      const Home = () => ({
        template: `
          <div>
            Home
          </div>`,
      });
      const About = () => ({
        template: `
          <div>
            About
          </div>`,
      });

      const router = createRouter({
        history: createWebHistory(),
        routes: [
          { path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home },
          { path: "/about", name: "About", component: About },
        ],
      });

      setup((app: App) => {
        app.use(router);
      });

      return {
        template: "<div><story /><router-view /></div>",
      };
    },
  ],
}
```